# How do you edit your static pages on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, static, content-management-system, themes

This may come across as a stupid question but I am really struggling. I have always built websites manually so HTML, CSS, jQuery are no issue for me.  However I have started to use WordPress and I am finding it hard to add additional static pages.

E.g Home, About, Contact etc... I have gotten to the point of having the home page working but when it comes to adding addition pages I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

I have added all the pages and I can navigate to those pages but where do I add my code? Where do I add the HTML? I have tried adding text to my theme but it doesn't display anything when I view the page.

I can only assume I have left something out or broken something.

http://www.officiallaurenwaterworth.co.uk/wp/

Any help would be amazing! I'm at my wits end!

---

Footer -

```
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            jQuery(".dropdown").mouseenter(function(){
            jQuery(".drop-nav").stop(true, true).slideDown(1000);

            });

            jQuery(".drop-nav-container").mouseleave(function(){
            jQuery(".drop-nav").stop(true, true).slideUp(500)

            }); 
});
</script>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Header -

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: LaurenWaterworth
*/
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            <?php   
                wp_title('|',true,'right'); 
                bloginfo('name');
            ?>
        </title>
            <?php
                add_action('wp_head', '');
            ?>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/style.css">  
        <?php wp_head();?>
    </head>
    <body class="page-id-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="container">
            <header>
                <div class"five columns clearfix">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_option('home');?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/logo.png" title="bloginfo('title');"></a>
                </div>


                <div class="drop-nav-container">
                    <p class="dropdown">MENU</p>
                        <div class="drop-nav">
                            <div class="sixteen columns nav-bar">
                                <?php wp_nav_menu(  array('container_class' => 'main-nav','container'=>'nav'));?>

                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </header>
```

Comment: Oh and when I visit the new pages my jQuery stops working for the nav bar...

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is a not only a blog framework, but more recently became a CMS. With that being said, you don't have to work with any HTML if the theme is built correctly.

In your admin backend on the left side you should see a tab called "Pages". You can edit a physical page just like you would edit posts. You input content, press save and thats it.

Now if you wan't to work with the styling or HTML you can press "Themes" on the left side and press edit on your current theme. Once you press edit you will see all the files, including the PHP, HTML and CSS.

Comment: I know how to add pages. It is just that the content on the site isn't displaying on the pages and the Nav bar breaks when you click on the nav links.

Comment: @marchogan you have to be more detailed. I have zero clue what your talking about.

Comment: I have started to create a static site from scratch. I need to add  all the pages to the site. Once I have added then using 'pages' "add page'. I add them into my registered Nav. Then when I go into each page and physically type in the box where the content should go, none of what I write shows up on the page. Do I need to add a loop before it will display anything?

Comment: @marchogan did you choose the right page template? http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Comment: I believe so as it does display the Nav bar properly apart from the jQuery only working on the home page.

Comment: @marchogan I need to see some code. Show me your jQuery as well as your Page template and index.

Comment: Index - <?php
get_header();
if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_post();
      the_content();
   endwhile;
endif;
get_sidebar();
get_footer(); 
?>